# Biphenyl symmetry group dependence on torsional angle

Tags: organic-chemistry, symmetry

What is the symmetry group of the biphenyl when the torsional angle between the phenyls is 20 degrees? What about when it is 90 degrees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $20$ degree structure exhibits the $D_2$ point group and the $90$ degree $D_{2d}$.

The figure below shows an $D_{2d}$ structure (a spiropentadiene) but the similarity in symmetry should be clear (I hope ). (From molecule-viewer.com)

[image: spiro-penta D2d]

The biphenyl at an angle not $90$ degrees is shown below

[image: biphenyl D2]